# No me muestra la tabla correctamente al crearla con $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente tabla generada con Datatables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, dentro de la columna Premio, quiero crear una tabla común (sin datatables), de la forma que lo hago es llamando a una función que se llama insertTablePositionDraw;

```
"columns": [                        
    {
        "data": "prize_money",
        "name": "draws.prize_money",
        "mRender": function (data, wea, row, meta) {
             return row.prize_money
                ? '$<strong>' + data + ' </strong>' +
                '<i class="fa fa-bar-chart create-prize-money" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCreatePrizeMoney"></i>' +
                  '<br/>' + (row.positions != "" ? insertTablePositionDraw(row.positions) : '')
                    : '';
              }
    },
 ]
```

La función llamada es la siguiente:

```
function insertTablePositionDraw(data){

   return '<table class="table table-bordered">' +
           '<thead>'+
                '<tr>' +
                     '<th class="text-center">Posición</th>' +
                     '<th class="text-center">Premio</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
           '</thead>'+
           '<tbody>'+
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                   `<tr>`+
                       `<td>`+
                           data.position;
                        `</td>`+
                        `<td>`+
                           data.pivot.dato;
                        `</td>`+
                   `</tr>`
                })
           '</tbody>'
      '</table>'
}
```

de esta forma no me crea correctamente la tabla, no me muestra los datos

Comment: No es que el `$.each` en sí no funcione, es que el código compartido tiene bastantes errores.

Comment: Como cuales?, estoy buscando por todo google y no me funciona lo que veo. Si podrías corregir mi tabla o darme una mano te agradecería @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Debes actualizar tu pregunta para que sea más fácil trabajar con ella. Lee [ask] y crea un [mcve] (pon un ejemplo pequeño del valor de data y de cómo estás usando la función `createTable()`)

Comment: Errores hay bastantes: te faltan operadores de concatenación, hay cadenas que no son cadenas, no se hace nada con el resultado obtenido, data se está utilizando mal dentro del `each`, esa manera de añadir código en el `each` no sirve para concatenar...

Comment: Ok, mejoro lo posteado y lo ves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errores en el post:

- Faltan operadores de concatenación (lo que haría que la cadena terminase antes de tiempo).
- Hay cadenas que no son cadenas (los delimitadores de cadena en JS son `'` y `"` pero no `` ` ``).
- No se hace nada con el resultado obtenido (deberías devolverlo con un `return` o escribirlo en algún elemento o algo).
- Esa manera de añadir el `each` no sirve para concatenar (deberías crear una cadena auxiliar y rellenarla antes, dentro y después del `each`).
- La variable `data` se está utilizando mal dentro del `each` (deberías hacer `data[index]` o usar `item` para acceder a `position` o `pivot`).

Aquí puedes ver los errores en tu código con comentarios:

```
function createTable(){
   // NO SE DEVUELVE O HACE NADA
   '<table class="table table-bordered">' +
           '<thead>'+
                '<tr>' +
                     '<th class="text-center">Posición</th>' +
                     '<th class="text-center">Premio</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
           '</thead>'+
           '<tbody>'+
                // EACH NO DEVUELVE NADA QUE SE PUEDA CONCATENAR
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                   // ESTAS USANDO ` EN LUGAR DE ' O "
                   `<tr>`+
                       `<td>`+
                           data.position; // ; EN LUGAR DE +
                        `</td>`+
                        `<td>`+
                           data.pivot.dato; // ; EN LUGAR DE +
                        `</td>`+
                   `</tr>`
                }) // TE FALTA UN +
           '</tbody>'
      '</table>'
}

// NO SE HACE NADA CON EL RESULTADO DE LA FUNCION
```

Corrigiendo eso, el resultado queda así y ya funciona:

```js
var data = [{
  position: 1,
  pivot: {
    dato: 2
  }
}]

function createTable() {

  var aux = '<table class="table table-bordered">' +
              '<thead>' +
                '<tr>' +
                  '<th class="text-center">Posición</th>' +
                  '<th class="text-center">Premio</th>' +
                '</tr>' +
              '</thead>' +
              '<tbody>';

  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    aux += '<tr>' +
             '<td>' +
               data[index].position +
             '</td>' +
             '<td>' +
               data[index].pivot.dato +
             '</td>' +
           '</tr>';
  });

  aux +=   '</tbody>'
         '</table>'
  return aux;
}

document.getElementById("tabla").innerHTML = createTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabla"></div>
```

Comment: Impecable! Muchas  gracias